# Is there a more efficient version of this SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I've got the below SQL statement which runs in MySQL on a WordPress installation. I'm looking for meta data that matches certain criteria and was created after a certain date.

However, WordPress doesn't store the date that metadata was added to posts, so I've created the metadata itself (wpcf-post-likes), the date it was added (wpcf-post-like-date) and a third piece of metadata which is created at the same time that contains the IDs of the previous two delimited by an exclamation mark (wpcf-post-like-date-link).

I then use the following SQL statement to get likes on posts written by the current author (example ID included in the SQL code below) after a certain date. It works, but it takes about 7 - 8 seconds to run, which is far from ideal. Is there a more efficient version of the same statement?

```
SELECT `meta_id` FROM `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE   `post_id` IN (
            SELECT `ID` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_author = $user_id
        ) AND
        `meta_value` IN (

        SELECT CONCAT(combined_ids_a.`meta_id`, '!', combined_ids_b.`meta_id`) AS `combined_meta_id` FROM (

            SELECT `meta_id`, 'like_id' AS `meta_type` FROM `wp_postmeta` 
            WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'wpcf-post-likes'
            AND `meta_value` NOT LIKE '1837'
            AND `meta_id` IN 
            (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`meta_value`, '!', 1) FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'wpcf-post-like-date-link' ORDER BY `meta_id` DESC)

            UNION

            SELECT  `meta_id`, 'like_date' AS `meta_type`  FROM `wp_postmeta` 
            WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'wpcf-post-like-date'
            AND `meta_value` > '01-02-2016 09:20:34'
            AND `meta_id` IN 
            (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`meta_value`, '!', -1) FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'wpcf-post-like-date-link' ORDER BY `meta_id` DESC)

        ) AS combined_ids_a JOIN 

        (

            SELECT `meta_id`, 'like_id' AS `meta_type` FROM `wp_postmeta` 
            WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'wpcf-post-likes'
            AND `meta_value` NOT LIKE '1837'
            AND `meta_id` IN 
            (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`meta_value`, '!', 1) FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'wpcf-post-like-date-link' ORDER BY `meta_id` DESC)

            UNION

            SELECT  `meta_id`, 'like_date' AS `meta_type`  FROM `wp_postmeta` 
            WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'wpcf-post-like-date'
            AND `meta_value` > '01-02-2016 09:20:34'
            AND `meta_id` IN 
            (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`meta_value`, '!', -1) FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'wpcf-post-like-date-link' ORDER BY `meta_id` DESC)

        ) AS combined_ids_b    

        );
```

Comment: In order to help you, we would need to see the structure of the tables involved, some data sample from each of then and what would be your desired result. Also, and explain plan of the current query would also help. It is really hard to help you improve your select without knowing nothing about your structure. So try to help us so we can help you!

Comment: I don't know the MySQL optimizer, but when you do IN, there's no need for UNION instead of UNION ALL, and for ORDER BY.

Comment: This query looks wrong. You are selecting meta IDs for "likes" and "like dates" and cross join this result with itself. Is this desired or a typical MySQL error where you simply forgot the ON clause?

Comment: Apart from that: UNION seems wrong here. The UNION doesn't produce duplicates (as the meta_type column differs), so there are no duplicates to remove from this operation. The only thing it does is do a post distinct on the two intermediate results ("likes" and "like dates"). Probably a UNION ALL would suffice. Or do you want to remove duplicate meta_ids, for this is the only field you access later? Then remove the meta_type column to make it work.

Comment: Moreover an ORDER BY in an IN clause makes no sense and can result in having the DMBS do more work than necessary.

Comment: I've changed it to UNION ALL and removed the ORDER BY to no noticeable difference. @ThorstenKettner - The cross join allows me to rejoin the IDs and match against the value in the third meta_value, post-like-date-link, which is composed of 2 ids delimited by an exclamation mark.

Comment: It seems I just don't understand how the tables are related. If I get meta_id 1 in "like" and meta_id 2 in "like date", I get '1!1', '1!2', '2!1' and '2!2'. And one or several of these combined IDs can match the meta_value in wp_postmeta? This looks so random, somehow.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - The idea is to get all possible combinations of the data returned. So if the query returns 1, 2, and 3, that join returns 1!1,1!2,1!3,2!1,2!2,2!3,3!1,3!2,3!3.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_postmeta`; you seem to have non-standard datatypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are dealing with a key-value table, so performance issues are kind of natural.

You cross-self-join an ad-hoc view (a derived table), which is something very special, but shouldn't be a big problem for the DBMS. It should notice that you have the same subquery twice in your query and only process it once. (However, when cross joining you should use a `CROSS JOIN` explicitly, so as to show that this is on purpose and you didn't merely forgot the `ON` clause as your use of a simple `JOIN` suggests.)

So what else is there to optimize? I already told you that you should replace `UNION` with `UNION ALL` if possible, and remove the `ORDER BY` in the `IN` clauses. Moreover you work with `LIKE` and `NOT LIKE` although you don't look for patterns. Maybe you are lucky and the DBMS scans your strings literals beforehand and notices that there is no pattern to search for at all, but maybe it doesn't. Don't give the DBMS more work to do than necessary and use `=` and `<>` instead.

Then you create a meta_type column that you never use, so why create it at all?

Anayway, you should have two composite indexes for this query: One on wp_postmeta(meta_key, meta_id, meta_value) in order to find the meta IDs quickly. The other on wp_postmeta(meta_key, meta_value). By the way: Can't you specify the meta_key for the outermost query? It looks strange to look up a value without the key.

The query becomes:

```
select meta_id 
from wp_postmeta 
where post_id in (select id from wp_posts where post_author = $user_id) 
and meta_value in 
(
  select concat(a.meta_id, '!', b.meta_id)
  from
  (
    select meta_id
    from wp_postmeta 
    where meta_key = 'wpcf-post-likes'
    and meta_value <> '1837'
    and meta_id in (select substring_index(meta_value, '!', 1) from wp_postmeta where meta_key like 'wpcf-post-like-date-link')
    union all
    select  meta_id
    from wp_postmeta 
    where meta_key = 'wpcf-post-like-date'
    and meta_value > '01-02-2016 09:20:34'
    and meta_id in (select substring_index(meta_value, '!', -1) from wp_postmeta where meta_key like 'wpcf-post-like-date-link')
  ) a 
  cross join 
  (
    select meta_id
    from wp_postmeta 
    where meta_key = 'wpcf-post-likes'
    and meta_value <> '1837'
    and meta_id in (select substring_index(meta_value, '!', 1) from wp_postmeta where meta_key like 'wpcf-post-like-date-link')
    union all
    select  meta_id
    from wp_postmeta 
    where meta_key = 'wpcf-post-like-date'
    and meta_value > '01-02-2016 09:20:34'
    and meta_id in (select substring_index(meta_value, '!', -1) from wp_postmeta where meta_key like 'wpcf-post-like-date-link')
  ) b 
);
```

Or with `OR` instead of `UNION ALL`:

```
select meta_id 
from wp_postmeta 
where post_id in (select id from wp_posts where post_author = $user_id) 
and meta_value in 
(
  select concat(a.meta_id, '!', b.meta_id)
  from
  (
    select meta_id
    from wp_postmeta 
    where 
    (
      meta_key = 'wpcf-post-likes'
      and meta_value <> '1837'
      and meta_id in (select substring_index(meta_value, '!', 1) from wp_postmeta where meta_key like 'wpcf-post-like-date-link' order by meta_id desc)
    )
    or
    (
      meta_key = 'wpcf-post-like-date'
      and meta_value > '01-02-2016 09:20:34'
      and meta_id in (select substring_index(meta_value, '!', -1) from wp_postmeta where meta_key like 'wpcf-post-like-date-link' order by meta_id desc)
    )
  ) a 
  cross join 
  (
    select meta_id
    from wp_postmeta 
    where 
    (
      meta_key = 'wpcf-post-likes'
      and meta_value <> '1837'
      and meta_id in (select substring_index(meta_value, '!', 1) from wp_postmeta where meta_key like 'wpcf-post-like-date-link' order by meta_id desc)
    )
    or
    (
      meta_key = 'wpcf-post-like-date'
      and meta_value > '01-02-2016 09:20:34'
      and meta_id in (select substring_index(meta_value, '!', -1) from wp_postmeta where meta_key like 'wpcf-post-like-date-link' order by meta_id desc)
    )
  ) b 
);
```

One more thing: meta_value contains a string. In case the key is 'wpcf-post-like-date', you expect it to contain a datetime string. However, it is still a string, so '02-01-1980 09:20:34' is bigger than '01-02-2016 09:20:34' for instance. In order to be able to compare *datetimes*, you should either store 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss' or convert to datetimes or timestamps.

Comment: Turn `IN ( SELECT ... )` into a `JOIN` wherever possible.  Then come back for more critique.

Comment: @Rick James: Why? `IN` clauses are very easy to read and maintain and should usually be the first choice. It is very easy to turn an `IN` clause into a `JOIN` (join distinct values) or into an `EXISTS` clause for that matter. While the join suggests one access method and `EXISTS` another, this is not necessarirly the case. The DBMS is free to choose whichever execution plan it likes better. As it is so simple to convert an `IN` clause, the DBMS optimizer should be aware of its options. MySQL was once known for being weak on `IN` clauses, but that's hopefully a thing of the past.

Comment: Yeah, the DBMS is "free to choose"; but MySQL historically has chose the worst way to evaluate that.